# Missing required configuration "key.converter" which has no default

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When I try to start Kafka connect for elastic search reactor, in stand alone mode I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "key.converter" which has no default value.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:463)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:453)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:75)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.<init>(WorkerConfig.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.<init>(DistributedConfig.java:272)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:72)
```

Can I solve this error?

EDIT 01/05/2018
Sorry I try to be more specific. I Use the stream reactor connector:
https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor
This is the command that I launch from an EC2 instance in which there is the unique broker of my kafka:

```
./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/elastic-config.properties config/connect- 
standalone.properties.
```

In order this is connect-standalone.properties:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some 
settings.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it 
into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when 
loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's 
setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable 
and must be specified, but most users will
# always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never 
visible outside of Copcyat in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/home/ubuntu/kafka_2.11-1.0.1/libs
```

And this is the other file:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=test
    topic.index.map=test:test_index
    connection.url=myurl
    type.name=log
    key.ignore=true
    schema.ignore=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error kinda says it all. You're missing a required configuration entry, for `key.converter`. This tells Kafka Connect how to deserialise the data on the Kafka topic (JSON or Avro, usually).

You can see an example of a valid connector configuration for Elasticsearch here in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/975707be38b452f79347cde065b2322b). If you update your question to include the configuration you're using, I can point out how to incorporate it.

---

After seeing your config, the cause of your error is that you're invoking Connect with your config files in the wrong order, and hence Connect can't find the config it is expecting.

Should be:

```
./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/elastic-config.properties
```

---

Read more about streaming from Kafka to Elasticsearch in [this article](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/06/streaming-data-from-kafka-into-elasticsearch/), and this general series on using Kafka Connect:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: I have update my question adding configuration file. Can you give me an help to resolve this error? 
Thank you

Comment: Ah - you're invoking it in the wrong order. Needs to be `worker-config connector-config`, i.e. `./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect- 
standalone.properties config/elastic-config.properties`